# Deploying with CircleCI - SSH into server requires password but I have SSH key associated

Tags: ssh, devops, ssh-keys

I am trying to SSH into the server as part of the deployment job in CircleCI

`ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $DEV_DROPLET_USER@$DEV_DROPLET_IP`

I have my SSH private key for the user on this server loaded into CircleCI but everytime I run the job, I get this output

`Warning: Permanently added '$host' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
<$user>@<$host>'s password:`

How can I stop it prompting me for the password?

I have added the SSH key for this user to the SSH Agent on the server ([these](http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent) instructions)

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1328919/284722

Answer (score 8):

For a passwordless ssh connection, you must:

- put the private ssh key into a file in the directory `$HOME/.ssh/` on the client computer connecting to the server (example : `$HOME/.ssh/MyServer`)
- copy the public ssh key into the file `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server
- have writing permission on the file `$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts` on the client computer

The sshd service is normally already configured to accept key based authentication.

From the client computer, you can now do a passwordless connection `ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/MyServer $DEV_DROPLET_USER@$DEV_DROPLET_IP`

Of course, on the client computer your $DEV_DROPLET_USER must have appropriate permissions for accessing the ssh related files.

You don’t need to do anything with the ssh agent, on the client or on the server.

Comment: The client here is the docker image running on CircleCI, so , how/where to store the private key there?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I hope it helps somebody else in the future.

Assuming you followed [these instructions in the CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/add-ssh-key/), then the private key will automatically be copied to the machine being used by CircleCI when the `add_ssh_keys` step is run.

Make sure one the server you are trying to SSH into, the public key generated (in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or something similar) is copied to the `~/.ssh/authorized_hosts` file on the same server. This crucial step is what allows anybody with the private key (CircleCI) to be allowed into the server.